# Print a middle character of a string

Tags: c

I must write a program in C that can print the middle letter of the string you entered. Spaces () are also calculated, and the number of characters must be odd.

Ex. Input

```
Hi sussie
```

-->  9 characters, including space

The output should be `s`.

I have tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char x[100];


int main(void) 
{
  printf("Hello World\n");

  scanf("%c\n",&x);

  long int i = (strlen(x)-1)/2;
  printf("the middle letter of the word is %c\n",x[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

and the output always shows the first letter of the word I have entered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking for homework help and no attempt was made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Babud Could you explain how you goit 14 characters for the string  "Hi sussie"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have tried using strlen to find the length of word an then print the print its middle character

Comment: @SumnerEvans I forgot to include it

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I edited it, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only reading the first character from `stdin` (and incorrectly; you shouldn't be using `&`).

If you must use `scanf`, you should use this format:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", x);
```

This is safe and doesn't read past the buffer.

Note that `%s` wouldn't work here. `%s` causes `scanf` to interpret whitespace as the end of the string.

A much better, safer, and easier solution would be to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`; `fgets` is safer and it doesn't require you to change a format string when you change the size of your array:

```
fgets(x, sizeof(x)-1, stdin);
```

This eliminates any possible issues with whitespace or buffer overflow.

Comment: Nice it work. can you explain to me why using '%99' , what the meaning of 99?

Comment: @Babud It doesn't read past the buffer. Say someone enters 334 characters, if you don't have that there, your program will crash. If you do have it there, it will just read the first 99. It's because the size of your buffer is 100 characters, and you need 1 character for the terminating null byte.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
        char arr[1024];
        char a;
        int i,counter=0;

        printf("enter string :: ");
        fgets(arr,sizeof(arr),stdin);

        for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
                counter++;

        for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
        {
                if(i==(counter/2))
                        printf("%c\n",arr[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.